# Multiple database queries in parallel, for a single client request

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, hector

To complete certain requests from the user, in my application, I am issuing multiple DB queries from a single method, but they are currently being executed sequentially & thus the application is blocked until the time it has received the response/data for the previous query, then proceeding to next query. This is not something I like much. I would like to issue parallel queries.

Also after issuing queries I would like to do some other work, (instead of being blocked till previous queries response) & on getting the response for each query I would like to execute a code block specific to each query's data. What is the way to do this ?

Edit:My DB API does provide connection pooling.

---

I'm *just a little bit* familiar with Java multithreading.

```
Using:-
------
Java 1.6
Cassandra 1.1 Database with Hector
```

Comment: This is a lot of intricacies here.  I'd recommend starting by doing a good bit of reading about threading in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

You should understand before you start doing this

1. To benefit from concurrency, you need to have multiple db connections. THe best way to solve this is to create a db pool.
2. You need to create a runnable / callable class for executing a db Statement. You will need to put together some messaging system to alert listeners to when your query has completed
3. Understand that when you are sending multiple requests at the same time, all bets are off as to which will complete first, and that there may be conflicts between statements that destabilize your app.

Comment: My DB access API provides connection pooling. Do I need to be sure about what among multiple data queries will complete first ? Cant it be like whatever completes first it leads to execution of its specific code block?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar task/issue. For complete build result I need to send few requests for few different service (few on REST, few on Thrift), for decrease latency I need to sent it in parallel. My idea is using java.util.concurrent.Future, make simple aggregation manager , which create many requests together and will be wait last retrieved response and return all needed data. In more advanced solution this manager can make/combine final result during other queries, but this solution can be not thread safe.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a very trivial/limited approach:

```
final Connection conn = ...;
final Object[] result = new Object[1];
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Object results = conn.executeQuery();
        result[0] = results;
    }
});
t1.setName("DBQueryWorker");
t1.start();
// do other work
while (t1.isAlive()) {
   // wait on thread one
}
```

This is a simple approach, but many others are possible (eg, thread pooling via Java Concurrency task executors, Spring task executors, etc).

Comment: This is essentially single-threaded, as you only have 1 Connection object, and the main thread waits (in the wrong way - should use join()) on the request thread

Comment: @user1291492: Incase this solution is wrong, could you add some code examples/hints about how to implement this, in your answer ?

Comment: I don't think it's fair at all to say that this is single threaded. His "other work" could easily be done while the connection is busy (assuming it doesn't use it). Ultimately, he will likely need more than one connection to deal with his multiple threads scenario, but this was a basic example, not a full solution.

I agree with the suggestion to use join instead of the busy-wait at the end, though.