# Calling procedure from java code

Tags: java, call, procedure

I am calling procedure from java code:

```
private String processData(Integer time, String jndiName) {
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        InitialContext ctxt = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctxt.lookup(jndiName);
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        cs = conn.prepareCall("{call PROC(?)}");
        cs.setInt(1, time);
        cs.execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

This procedure just waiting for X second which I set as parameter.

**The question is:**

How long will take this java function when I call this procedure with parameter `time=30`?

It will wait untill this procedure ends or java will just run it and continue to next command ?

Comment: btw, slightly unrelated, but you should close the connection in a finally block (otherwise you would run in to connection leaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will wait, it's a blocking operation.

Comment: hm is there some options how I can run this in another thread and continue in application ?

Comment: Create a class that implements `Runnable` and wrap the `processData` method inside `run`. Then, you can just call it like this `new Thread(new YourRunnable()).start()`.

Comment: @hudi [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932653/multiple-database-queries-in-parallel-for-a-single-client-request) may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

CS.execute is a blocking call, waits for the database to complete the procedure call and then only returns.